# Azure Application Insights Metrics(Preview) Deployment process

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azureportal

Using azure portal's application insights' menu, a user can assemble data and pin it to the Azure portal Dashboard like so:
[Metrics(preview) - pin to dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRzjz.png)

I am tasked with creating many of these dashboards in multiple environments, and would rather write some kind of script once instead of manually doing this multiple times.

**Is there anyway to automate this process?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the same data shared in multiple environments then you could [create and share a dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards). If it's different data in each environment. Then your best bet may be to use some browser automation software like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). You can set it up to create and pin the dashboard part and then run it in the different environments. Keep in mind, that while the script you write with Selenium may work when you write it, it can possibly break in the future if the HTML of the page changes.

Comment: I indeed did end up using create and share functionality.  In my case, we couldn't deploy directly to the production environment since that account is completely separate from our development environment.  Instead I followed the directions at [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards-create-programmatically](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards-create-programmatically) for pulling down the JSON for the dashboard, then using AzureRM in powershell to write a deployment script that pushes this JSON up to the prod account.

Comment: Ah yeah I forgot sharable dashboards are actually resources that can be deployed. Glad you were able to solve your problem in a supported programmatic way.